# Postfix sendmail with a different origin domain

Tags: email, ip-address, sendmail, postfix-mta

This is probably a really basic question...

I have multiple sites with unique ips and I'm trying to `sendmail` from each with *it's own* address. I've read all the questions here about using transport maps to achieve this etc...

Sender dependent transport maps only works when I set `myorigin` in `main.conf` to certain domain. This is exactly what I want but it requires *restarting* postfix everytime I change myorigin.

So my question is, how can I set myorigin on the fly, i.e. when I'm actually *sending* mail from the command line?

I've tried using the `-C` option to read a different config file with the `sendmail` command but it never overrides the values in `main.conf`.

How do I tell postfix that the mail is being sent from a certain domain when I use the `sendmail` command?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple. Just use the `-f` option on sendmail and set it to "webmaster@domain.com".